# How to center align table contents in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following

```
output$view <- renderTable({
tmp <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=1,ncol=2))
tmp[1,1] <- "1"
tmp[1,2] <- "2"
head(tmp,n=nrow(tmp))
})
```

The contents of the data frame are not centered. How could I center it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use CSS, do this.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          '
          #view{
            text-align:center;
          }
          '
        )
      )
    ),
    tableOutput('view')
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  output$view <- renderTable({
    tmp <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=1,ncol=2))
    tmp[1,1] <- "1"
    tmp[1,2] <- "2"
    head(tmp,n=nrow(tmp))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```